# Bluesky の投稿 URL 末尾から何が分かりますか？

Tags: url

#### 知りたいこと

`3kmzkcbnsv52t` と `3kmzkjebart2h` から何が読み取れるか知りたい

URL例

- `https://bsky.app/profile/xxxx.bsky.social/post/3kmzkcbnsv52t`
- `https://bsky.app/profile/zzzz.bsky.social/post/3kmzkjebart2h`

#### できれば知りたいこと

このURLの末尾部分がどういう規則に基づいて付与されているか知りたい

#### 質問

`3kmzkcbnsv52t` と `3kmzkjebart2h` を比較して `3kmzkjebart2h` の方が大きかったら(アルファベットが後だったら？)、`https://bsky.app/profile/zzzz.bsky.social/post/3kmzkjebart2h` の投稿日時は `https://bsky.app/profile/xxxx.bsky.social/post/3kmzkcbnsv52t` より後だと言えますか？

Comment: 提示された URL はどちらも存在しないアドレスのようです。例であるなら予め断りを入れるか、存在する URL を提示した方が親切だと思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

それは[Record Key](https://atproto.com/specs/record-key)(rkeyとも、以下rkeyと記載)とい言われるものです。rkeyには三つのタイプがあります。

- `tid`
- `literal:<value>`
- `any`

`tid`はマイクロ秒レベルの現在時刻と同じ時刻では単純増加するクロック識別子の組をソート可能なBASE32でエンコードすることで求められます。`tid`は必ず時刻順になるという特徴があります。

`literal:<value>`は特定の意味を示すrkeyです。よく知られたモノは`literal:self`です。

`any`は何でもありです。実際は使用できる文字や文字数に制限がありますが、制限内であり、かつ、ユニークになるようであれば、何でも構いません。

もし、`tid`であれば、BASE32としてデコードすることでレコードの日時がマイクロ秒レベルでわかります。ただ、`tid`を採用しているかどうかはサービスによるため、異なるサービス(BlueskyではないAT PROTOCOL実装)ではそうではない可能性がありますし、正確性も担保されません。Blueskyは`tid`を使用していますが、[Record Key TIDs](https://docs.bsky.app/docs/advanced-guides/timestamps#record-key-tids)にもrkeyを解析してタイムスタンプを取り出すことは止めることを推奨すると記載されています。

なお、ドキュメントではclock identifireが10bitsとありますが、bsky.appにある実際の投稿を見ると9bitsのようです。私の計算がおかしいのか、ドキュメントが間違っているのか、現在の実装がドキュメントとずれているのかまではわかりません。

---

参考までに、検証するために作ったtidをパースするRubyスクリプトを記載しておきます。(実行には[Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/ja/)と[base32](https://rubygems.org/gems/base32) gemが必要です。スクリプトの使い方についての問い合わせは受け付けません。)

```
require 'base32'
def parse_tid(str)
  h, l = Base32.decode(str.tr('234567abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567')).unpack('N2')
  Time.at(*(((h << 32) + l) >> 9).divmod(1_000_000))
end
ARGV.each { |str| pp parse_tid(str) }
```

Comment: リンク提示ありがとうございます。Blueskyが採用しているAT Protocolの仕様として規定されているのですね。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 3):

いきなり余談ですが、質問からは(ほかの質問もそうなのですが)背景や目的が全く読み取れないので、回答の粒度とか一般論/特定条件の温度感が求められてるものと乖離している可能性が大いにあります。そういう観点では「意味はない」という回答を信じてもらう方が現実にはよいことかもしれません。

---

本題：

適当にピックアップしてみるとどうも時系列になってるようです。

- 直近のもの 3kmz...
- 2週間程前  3kly...
- 1ヶ月前　3kks...

ハッシュ値では時系列は出てきませんしそもそもこのような文字列の類似が起こりません。よってハッシュ値ではあり得ません。

Answer (score 1):

#### 短い答え:

特に読み取れる情報はありません。

#### もう少しだけ詳しく:

恐らく何らかのハッシュ関数で生成した "ユニークな文字列" であろうと推測されます。
単純な連番だと被る可能性があるからでしょうか？

[Qiita](https://qiita.com/) や [teratail](https://teratail.com/) , [note](https://note.com/) などの web サービスでも個別投稿には類似の URL が生成される仕組みになっているはずです。